# Advanced user info in database

Tags: database, database-design, data-binding

I'm creating an `Account` table in my project's database. Each account has A LOT of properties:

- login
- email
- password
- birthday
- country
- avatarUrl
- city
- etc.

Most of them are nullable. My question is, **how should I design this in database?**

Should it be one table with all those properties? Or maybe should I create two tables, like `AccountSet`, and `AccountInfoSet`, where I would store all those 'advanced' user's settings? And last, but not least: if this should be two tables, what kind of relation should be between those tables?

Comment: Have you reduced any redundant information? It is surprising how much information you can get rid of.

Comment: Oh, I'm only asking about the general idea, don't look at those examples(birthday, country) as my strict data. I just want to know the general idea of how to manage the case where I have to store a lot of info.

Comment: It depends. I would prefer to segment data into separate tables to avoid cluttering. A well designed database with linked tables would be more versatile to change, add, and manipulate. If your data is comprised entirely of single entities with 1:1 correlation (I.e each row has mutually exclusive information for any other row) a single table would probably be best.

From a performance standpoint, column number will have negligible effect up until multiple thousand columns. However, storage of a particularly large database could be a problem, if attributes are optional, and commonly left null.

Comment: If this was the case, it would be far more beneficial to split the optional attributes into a seperate table and reference to the parent table by means of FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a relational database, then I definitely would *not* store those properties as fields in the Account table.  Some reasons why:

1. Once your application goes to production (or maybe it's already there), the schema maintenance will become a nightmare.  You will absolutely add more properties and having to constantly touch that table in production will be painful.
2. You will most likely end up with orphaned fields.  I've seen this many times where you'll introduce a property and then stop using it, but it's baked into your schema and you might be too scared to remove it.
3. Ideally you want to avoid having such sparse data in a table (lots of fields with lots of nulls).

My suggestion would be to do what you're already thinking about and that's to introduce a property table for Accounts.  You called it AccountInfoSet.

The table should look like this:

AccountId int,
Property nvarchar(50),
Value nvarchar(50)

(Of course you'll set the data types and sizes as you see fit.)

Then you'll join to the AccountInfoSet table and maybe pivot on the "advanced" properties - turn the rows into columns with a query.

In .NET you can also write a stored procedure that returns two queries with one call and look at the tables in the DataSet object.

Or you could just make two separate calls.  One for Account and one for the properties.

Lots of ways to get the information out, but make sure you don't just add fields to Account if you're using a relational database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have just one question. Will it be efficient if I have, let's say, a million users and about 10 properties. If everybody would actually fill all the personal data, this table would become quite huge. Should I use sth else if I would know, that most of users will fill that data, or is it ok?

Comment: Even with a million users and 10 properties I think it will be ok. But like with anything once you start to scale, you might find yourself having to be more creative. I would cross that bridge when you come to it, but usually around one to two million in a relational database is just fine.